# Change the style of some elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

i have this navBar on top of layout page:

```
<div id="myTopnav" class="topnav" style="background-color: #030005; background-image: linear-gradient(#270133,#F5F5F5)">
            <a href="#" class="active ">@Session["UserName"].ToString() @Session["UserApe"].ToString()</a>
            <a href="#">Testing A</a>
            <a href="#">Testenado B</a>
            <a href="/Home/Logout">Cerrar Sesion</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="despMenu()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
```

The idea is to switch the gradient on each  button nad ofr that i have come to this:

```
window.addEventListener("load",inicializarEventos,false);
function inicializarEventos() {
    var ob1 = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    var lista = ob1.getElementsByTagName("a");    
    var sw = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < (lista.length - 1); i++) {
        if (sw == 1) {
            ob1.item(i).style.backgroundImage="linear-gradient(to top ,#270133,#F5F5F5)";            
            sw = 0;
            console.log("Entro a 1")
            break;
        }
        else {
            ob1.item(i).style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to top ,#F5F5F5,#270133)";
            sw = 1;
            console.log("Entro a 2")
             }
      }
}
```

However it isnt working. What am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: "it isnt working" is not a problem statement. How does it not work?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: ob1.item is not a function
    at inicializarEventos (VM647 Ord.js:8)
inicializarEventos @ VM647 Ord.js:8
load (async)
(anonymous) @ VM647 Ord.js:1

Comment: That is what the console throws at loading @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: if you want to have the item at index i you would need to use ob1.item[i]

Comment: @cloned or simply `lista[i]`

Comment: Also, is there any reason you're skipping the last element?

Comment: `ob1.item(i)` should be `ob1.item[i]`  first one means you are trying to call a function called item passing i into it, second one is an array object - don't mix up your bracket types

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it worked wiht lista[i] . Also the last element its a hidden button that doenst need the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working rxample should look like:

```
window.addEventListener("load",inicializarEventos,false);
function inicializarEventos() {
    var ob1 = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    var lista = ob1.getElementsByTagName("a");    
    var sw = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i  < lista.length; i++) {
        if (sw == 1) {
            lista[i].style.backgroundImage="linear-gradient(to top ,#270133,#F5F5F5)";            
            sw = 0;
            console.log("Entro a 1")
            break;
        }
        else {
            lista[i].style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to top ,#F5F5F5,#270133)";
            sw = 1;
            console.log("Entro a 2")
             }
      }
}
```

As mentioned above you should use `lista[i]` for accessing your current object and also you should check your entire list if there are no restrictions `i  < lista.length`

Comment: Thanks mate, it was that